# How do I find the ID of the canvas generated by Kinetic?

Tags: kineticjs

After I create the canvas I want using Kinetic, I want to manipulate it in other ways. I can't find out in the documentation the ID of the canvas created by Kinetic. I want to grab it by using getElementById. Thanks for your time.

Comment: see http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shape-by-id-with-kineticjs/ for more info

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it seems that example uses getElementById to grab the button, not the canvas.

Comment: the general consensus is to create a <div> with an id which is the one kineticjs will be using. Also, since it is a canvas, cant you do getElementByTagName ? the tag name being canvas

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic does not define the Canvas with an ID, unfortunately. Using the "getCanvas" Function might work, but you need to call it from a specific Layer. The best solution for me is to use the id of the div container and call "getElementsByTagName" to reach the Canvas element. But usually you only got one Canvas anyway, so you can just get it like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0]);
```

The only problem is that Kinetic creates a separate Canvas element for every Layer, so it´s best to use only one Layer in your projekt or you have to browse through them all:

```
var canvases = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
for (var i = 0; i < canvases.length; i++) {
    console.log(canvases[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would using `getCanvas()` work? (the [Kinetic documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Layer.php#getCanvas) just says it's used to "get layer canvas")

Additionally, I'm not sure if it's the same idea, but you might check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129614/kineticjs-animation-with-jquery).